# Утекает память из-за массива, хранящего DOM элементы

Tags: javascript, сборщик-мусора

Стал интересен вопрос управления памятью, насколько правильно понял, сборщик мусора производит очистку как только из корня больше нет ссылок на объект

Столкнулся со слегка не очевидным поведением, если удалить родительский контейнер, память под дочерние элементы продолжает выделятся, даже после вызова сборщика мусора(timeline)

Создаём много span'в, помещаем их на страницу и кэшируем элементы в массив, довольно часто так делаю, ибо удобно в дальнейшем к ним обращаться, затем понадобилось всё это дело удалить, если удалять элементы поштучно, затем массиву их хранившему даём любое другое значение, то память освобождается, но если удалить контейнер, то память не очищается

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test memory</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="start">start</button>
  <button id="destroyC">destroy children</button>
  <button id="destroyP">destroy parent</button>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var _elements = [];
    var _container = document.getElementById('container'),
      _btnStart = document.getElementById('start'),
      _btnParentDestoy = document.getElementById('destroyC'),
      _btnChildDestroy = document.getElementById('destroyP');

    function _start() {
      var element, count = 50000;
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        element = document.createElement('span')
        element.innerHTML = 'Span'
        _elements.push(element)
        _container.appendChild(element)
      }
    }

    function _destroyParent() {
      _container.remove()
      _elements.forEach(function(item, ind, arr) {
        arr[ind] = null;
      })
      console.log(_elements)
      _elements = null;
    }

    function _destroyChild() {
      _elements.forEach(function(item, ind, arr) {
        item.remove();
      })
      _elements = null;
    }

    _btnStart.addEventListener('click', _start)
     _btnParentDestoy.addEventListener('click', _destroyChild)
     _btnChildDestroy.addEventListener('click', _destroyParent)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: уберите `console.log`

Comment: Убрал, память всё равно течёт, в профайлере остаётся Detached DOM tree / 100001 entries